# Does Laravel Schema manages polymorphic associations out of the box?

Tags: php, polymorphic-associations, laravel

I'd like to create some *commentable* models for a project, but I cannot find any references to create the comments migration script, I've only found this video on vimeo: [Laravel 4 - Eloquent Collections & Polymorphic Relations](http://vimeo.com/53183075).

Am I supposed to add the polymorphic columns explicitly?

```
Schema::create('comments',function($table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->text('body');
    $table->string('commentable_type');
    $table->integer('commentable_id');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Question comes as the builder do expects the programmer when a key is a foreign key as in `$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polymorphic connections are nothing to do with Schema, they are an Eloquent feature which allows relationships to be built between any other type of model.

You can check the documentation for this:

http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships

Comment: I understand Schema and Eloquent are different concepts. I was wondering if there was a shortcut to add the polymorphic columns, just as `$table->timestamps()`. I gues that'd imply mixing logic with storage.

Comment: Right. I wasn't being patronising, I was just reinforcing the fact that they are not connected.

Comment: Schema says "here are the fields". Eloquent model then says "use these fields". Nothing to do with each other at all :)

Answer (score 6):

Laravel ~4.1 has a method to accomplish this:

```
$table->morphs('itemable');
```

Creates:

```
itemable_id
itemable_type
table_name_itemable_id_itemable_type_index
```

Second optional parameter is a replacement index name if the index is too long. The signature is:

```
public function morphs($name, $indexName = null);
```

Comment: Thanks man, the project was a proof of concept and the models & relationships were going crazy to implement without this and was scratched :(

Comment: Sorry to hear that. You can always implement polymorphism in Laravel just by specifying a string column "something_type" and an unsigned (incrementing) integer column "something_id".